# Ergo, per circulus in demonstrando sequitur contradictio ex praemissa

Tags: logic, translation-check

I want to capture the meaning of saying,

> Thus, contradiction follows from the premises by circular reasoning.

I'm fully aware of the logical problems of the content of the statement. My concern is the translation. Is the following correct?

> Ergo, per circulus in demonstrando sequitur contradictio ex praemissa.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to translate such an apparently nonsensical statement? I don't exactly feel compelled to make the effort...

Comment: In addition, take a look at [this meta question](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/what-do-we-do-with-translation-requests): it's great that you showed your translation attempt, but you should still point to actual issues you are wondering about.

Comment: I agree with @brianpck: The question would be better if you could tell what you are unsure about in your translation and what the context of the sentence is. Context really has an effect on translation, so it makes a difference whether or not it's in the context of mathematical logic or not, for example.

Comment: One small thing jumps out at me right away: _circulus_ should be in the accusative case: _per circulu**m** in demonstrando._ [Here's](https://books.google.com/books?id=6SUozv6nVT4C&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=%22per+circulum+in+demonstrando%22&source=bl&ots=piO_P1BVtw&sig=gbjnQSYFxgo_-M87FtHVxz-CDv8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG6rmdha_TAhUP8WMKHf6IB60Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22per%20circulum%20in%20demonstrando%22&f=false) an example. If you tell us some more about the context of the statement, someone here can probably figure out a good way to put it in Latin.

Comment: I'm writing (in English) about paralogisms and sophistical arguments. About half of my bibliography is comprised of Medieval logic books written in Latin and, although I can read Latin decently, I don't actually know how to speak/write Latin without it being obvious that I never studied the language. Yet, I frequently find myself wondering, "How would that be said in Latin?" This is the context that led me to wonder how, in Latin, to say, "Thus, by circular reasoning, contradiction follows from the premises."

Comment: Do you mean that a specific contradiction follows from certain premises, or a new contradiction, or a previously mentioned contradiction, or contradiction in general, or the essence of contradiction, or cosmic pandemonium, follows from the premises? The difference might matter more in English than in Latin: I'm asking because there's no article before "contradiction" in your question. Some context that could that clarify it might be the specific premises and contradiction that you have in mind—or, if you're speaking generally, then a made-up example or two.

Comment: A particular contradiction previously mentioned.